# Set the panning state of the forge viewer manually

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a case where I need to turn the panning state of the forge viewer on and off manually from a button custom button created outside the viewer. (Basically I need to recreate the functionality of the pan button within the forge viewer). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the navigation state can be switched by the code below:

```
//get current mode
myviewer.getActiveNavigationTool()
//switch to pan
myviewer.setActiveNavigationTool('pan')
```

you could simply create your button and trigger the method setActiveNavigationTool when the button is clicked. The choices are: "orbit", "freeorbit", "dolly", "pan","firstperson" etc.